# Angular 4 Cannot read property 'category' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-promise

Once again I think I lack understanding in Angular 4!

I have a page, accessed by a route and I'm trying to fetch a post by url-slug OnInit. The post resides in an array of Promises which I cache from the previous page (which is a list of posts page). The list page works fine. All my content caches and is read from a cache. I've tried switching this off, same problem occurs.

Here is the service that fetches the posts.

```
articles: Promise<Article[]>;

/**
   * fetch a list of articles
   */
  getArticles(): Promise<Article[]> {
    // cached articles
    if (this.articles) {
      return this.articles;
    }

    // no articles fetched yet, go get!
    return this.articles 
            = this.http.get(this.url, this.options)
                       .toPromise()
                       .then(response => response.json() as Article[])
                       .catch(this.handleError);
  }


  /**
   * fetch a single article by url slug
   * @param slug
   */
  getArticle(slug: string): Promise<Article> {
    return this.getArticles()
               .then(articles => articles.find(article => article.slug == slug));
  }
```

and this is what gets it on the SinglePost component:

```
article: Article

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getArticle();
  }

  getArticle(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.articleService.getArticle(params.get('name')))
        .subscribe(article => this.article = article);
  }
```

html:

```
<a href="" class="post-cat  text-uppercase">{{ article.category }}</a>
```

The posts (article as i've called it) are definitely present, and are definitely being read from the cache fine.

Moreover, although I get an error, the page still actually displays the correct article (I can confirm the article must be fetching correctly because of this), so I feel like it's trying to access the article object before its populated, I thought angular would handle that?

My error is:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'category' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PostComponent.html:4)
>       at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.es5.js?de3d:13105)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js?de3d:12256)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js?de3d:12599)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js?de3d:12531)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js?de3d:12257)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js?de3d:12599)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js?de3d:12531)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js?de3d:12257)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js?de3d:12599)

Comment: post your HTML code

Comment: first, why do you have `.toPromise()`? second, why do you do `return this.articles = this.http...` instead of `return this.http....`?

Comment: Posted, there's more, but you only need one example. The rest access the object exactly the same for different properties.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon because i'm using the tour of heroes example to learn. promises work for me, so i'd like to use promises.

Comment: I `return this.articles = this.http.get` because its simply returning the data, but at the same time assigning the data so I can use it for cache later

Comment: the return makes sense now, fair enough. but surely you either use `.toPromise()` or the `response => response.json()`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm just going by what angulars tutorial tells me to do. I don't really understand what you're asking me as I'm still new to angular 4

Comment: can you link the tutorial?

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Comment: i really dont get why their tutorial doesnt show the simple ways of doing things. its a weird way of doing things. a simple `.map()` and `.subscribe()` is all you ever need for returning and reading json data from a http call in angular

Comment: @mast3rd3mon could you elaborate? I'm learning from the angular tutorial, but if there's a better way and they're overcomplicating, then i'd love to know. I'm all for keeping it simple! I guess I need to read up on Observables as I don't get them yet! Coming from angularjs (1.x)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157876/discussion-between-mast3rd3mon-and-simon-www).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use elvis operator `?.`:

```
<a href="" class="post-cat  text-uppercase">{{ article?.category }}</a>
```

It will access the `category` property only if `article` is defined.

Comment: I'd have to use this throughout the whole component when accessing the property data, is this wise? Secondly, if I try and use say `[routerLink]="['/my-url', article?.slug]"` then it would fail as you can't supply a null value to routerLink

Comment: You could also add `*ngIf` on the whole container where you access this variable and if it is not available show some loader.

Comment: however, that wont render the html on the page

Comment: Actually @MartinAdámek that worked. It will render the html because as soon as article object exists the ngif will switch. I'm surprised angular doesn't handle that for you I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

use `then()` method instead of `subscribe()`

**service.ts**

```
articles: Promise<Article[]>;

/**
   * fetch a list of articles
   */
getArticles(): Promise<Article[]> {
    // cached articles
    if (this.articles) {
        return this.articles;
    }

    // no articles fetched yet, go get!
    return this.articles = this.http.get(this.url, this.options)
        .toPromise()
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}


/**
 * fetch a single article by url slug
 * @param slug
 */
getArticle(slug: string): Promise<Article> {
    return this.getArticles()
        .then(articles => articles.find(article => article.slug == slug));
}
```

**component.ts**

```
getArticle(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        this.articleService.getArticle(params.get('name'))
            .then(result => {
                console.log('result', result);
                this.article = result
            });
    })
}
```

Comment: @mast3rd3mon if you are using `map()` in the http method you can also use subscribe but here he using `then()` in the http call